# qt QComboBox setView to QTreeView can not do setCurrentIndex

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qcombobox

treecombobox.h

```
#ifndef TREECOMBOBOX_H
#define TREECOMBOBOX_H

#include <QComboBox>
#include "QAbstractItemView"
#include "QTreeView"

class TreeComboBox : public QComboBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TreeComboBox(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~TreeComboBox();

protected:
    QTreeView* internalView;

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // TREECOMBOBOX_H
```

treecombobox.cpp

```
#include "treecombobox.h"

TreeComboBox::TreeComboBox(QWidget *parent) :
    QComboBox(parent){

    this->internalView = new QTreeView( parent );
    this->setView( this->internalView );
    QAbstractItemModel* model = this->internalView->model();
    model->insertRows( 0, 2 );
    model->setData( model->index(0,0), "First" );
    model->setData( model->index(1,0), "Second" );
    this->view()->setCurrentIndex( model->index(1,0) );
}


TreeComboBox::~TreeComboBox(){
    if( this->internalView ){
        delete this->internalView;
        this->internalView = 0;
    }
}
```

I want to show the second item, but qt gives me the first item.
this->view()->currentIndex() gives me the correct model index, but the widget doesn't display correct content.

What I want is a combo box with tree view popup box. The popup box  works fine. The only problem is it goes wrong when I try to choose an item automatic in program.

Can some one tell me how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few time ago was meeting with the same question.

Can offer next solution (based on native QComboBox code and some internet stuff):

```
TreeComboBox::presetIndex(QModelIndex index)
{

        setRootModelIndex(index.parent());
        setModelColumn(index.column());
        setCurrentIndex(index.row());
        setRootModelIndex(QModelIndex());
        view->setCurrentIndex(index);
}
```

Sorry about formatting, first time and still not know how to make code-highlights here.

Comment: What/how/eeee? where did u got the index for this preestIndex function? I can't see any singnal in QComboBox that gives me that index...